# Subviewcontroller is added on navigation stack after picture is taken

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I have implemented camera feature into my application (inventoryviewcontroller).

After I take picture, then image is added on invetoryviewcontroller but sectionviewcontroller disappears. It seems that creates a navigation stack and adding inventoryviewcontroller on the top of sectionviewcontroller.

Once I click on submit button, inventoryviewcontroller disappears and sectionviewcontroller appears.

I am using ios 8 operating system on my device.

How could I able to fix that problem?

```
// SectionViewController.m 
       iViewController = (InventoryViewController *)[self.storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"InventoryViewController"];
        iViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(728, 32, 300, 736);
        [self.view addSubview:iViewController.view];
        iViewController.view.tag = 17;

  // InventoryVieController.m 
 - (IBAction)cameraBtn:(id)sender {
        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.allowsEditing = YES;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

    }

    - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
        UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
        self.noteImageView.image = chosenImage;
        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    }

    - (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    } 

  - (IBAction)submitBtn:(id)sender {
         UIView *viewToRemove = [self.view viewWithTag:17];
         [viewToRemove removeFromSuperview];
    }
```

[image]

Before image is taken:

[image]

After image is taken :

[image]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67272/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-casillas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turns out to be not adding the InventoryViewController as a child view controller, when its view is added to SectionViewController's view. So the code to do that looks like this,

```
    iViewController = (InventoryViewController *)[self.storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"InventoryViewController"];
    [self addChildViewController: iViewController];
    [iViewController didMoveToParentViewController: self];
    iViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(728, 32, 300, 736);
    [self.view addSubview:iViewController.view];
```

When removing the view, the child should also be removed (this code is in the child),

```
- (IBAction)submitBtn:(id)sender {
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [self removeFromParentViewController];
}
```